# Concatinating Long SMS using kannel

Tags: kannel

Kannel 1.4.4

I need to receive "long" sms (length > 160 ) by `Kannel`. If sms length less than 160 - all is ok. But if it is long sms kannel splits sms to 2 or more sms and  not send sms. I get this error from smsc log

> SMSC returned error code `0x000000ff` (Unknown Error) in response to submit_sm PDU

What can cause this error ?

Comment: SMS messages have a maximum length. Above that, any message must be split into multiple messages. You will need to investigate `kannel` support for that, or you might have to split the message yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation option for resolving this issue

---

max-messages = 3 
concatenation = true